# Wordpress Varnish Age=0 or Not Caching (Cookies?)

Tags: wordpress, caching, cookies, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm using Wordpress `3.8.1` and Varnish `3.0.5`. I'm sure the Varnish is not caching, because of the VCL nightmare. And i also don't know where is the very standard / correct VCL for Wordpress.

My Wordpress is **Multisite**, and i'm putting Varnish just on the top of the box, of Wordpress VM itself. `Varnish @ 8080` and `Apache @ 80/443`.

Since i don't know anything about VCL, i just used a random VCL i found:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .connect_timeout = 60s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 60s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 60s;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
            req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
        }
    }
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        if ( client.ip != "xx.xx.xx.xx") {
            error 405 "Not allowed.";
        }
        return (lookup);
    }
    if (req.request != "GET" &&
        req.request != "HEAD" &&
        req.request != "PUT" && 
        req.request != "POST" &&
        req.request != "TRACE" &&
        req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.request != "DELETE") {
            return (pipe);
    }
    if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }
    if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)") &&
        !(req.url ~ "&preview=true" ) ) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
        return (pass);
    }
    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged.";
    }
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged.";
    }
    return (fetch);
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        set beresp.ttl = 96h;
    }

    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
        beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
        beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
            set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
            return (hit_for_pass);
    }
    return (deliver);
}
```

*(and i used my ip for 'xx.xx.xx.xx')*

But anyway, this is NOT working by means of always getting `age : 0`. I've known the VCL has to handle the Wordpress COOKIES and other COOKIES, like G.A, etc.

How to do it, or where can i find the standard/correct VCL for Wordpress, please?

Comment: You have the correct function inside `vcl_recv` but I'm not sure if something else conflicts with it, though you should really remove all the default stuff, It's already executed by varnish it self.

Comment: Same problem here. The contents are all cached, such as images and css files, but the main page itself always says `Age: 0` in the header. Something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following varnish templates, the wordpress one is pretty decent. think thats the quickest way to success for your problem. manually fixing it based on your existing vcl will take more time.

https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/varnish-3.0-configuration-templates

Answer (score 0):

If the request contains any Cookie header, then Varnish won't cache that request.
If you see that requests to assets like images or css aren't cached you can remove the Cookie headers of that request, since they usually aren't needed, [check here](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleCacheCookies) form examples.

You can use the varnishlog command to see the logs in varnish in realtime. If you are doing this on your live site you can filter the logs, for example using:

```
varnishlog -m RxURL:/my/page.php
```

You can check the [documentation](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnishlog.html) for other params.

I wouldn't recommend to just use a random vcl that you found, you can grab that as a starting point then I encourage you to read the Varnish docs to understand what each rule does, many rules aren't actually needed since they are the default Varnish behavior. When you install varnish you can see the default.vcl file.

I Hope that helps.